# Remove duplicates from 3 vectors

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a problem in C++. Let's say I have 3 vectors  (don't mind the wrong definition, just an example)

```
a = {"a", "b"}, b = {"b", "c"}, c = {"b", "c"}
```

How can I most quickly and efficiently remove all duplicates from them, so the result is the following. There are no duplicates in one vector, and the vector isn't sorted alphabeticly.

```
a = {"a"}, b = {}, c = {}
```

Edit:
I've tried this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    {
        int i1 = findIndex(b, a[i]);
        int i2 = findIndex(c, a[i]);
        if (i1 != -1)
        {
            a.erase(a.begin() + i);
            b.erase(b.begin() + i1);
        }

        if (i2 != -1)
        {
            a.erase(a.begin() + i);
            c.erase(b.begin() + i2);
        }
}
```

where findIndex is:

```
int findIndex(vector<string> vec, string s)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        if (vec[i] == s)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Are the vectors sorted?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried. If you want to just know _how_, then you want to do some nested loops. An easy way: loop over each array's contents, for each of these iterations, loop over the other arrays. if the item is found, remove it from all arrays,

Comment: @VladfromMoscow They're of the vector<string> type, so I don't understand your question. Can you clarify?

Comment: Are they sorted containers is what Vlad is asking. Are the elements `{"a", "b", "c"}` (sorted) etc or `{"c", "a", "b"}` etc.

Comment: "remove all duplicates from them" if `A1` and `A2` are duplicates, then remove both of them?

Comment: a basic approach is count all the element, and remove those `count>=2` from `a,b,c`

Comment: I've edited the question to clear up some questions.

Comment: _"...and the vector isn't sorted alphabeticly..."_: without sorting (either on input or giving a sorted result) there is no efficient algorithm.  You need to just brute force it.

Comment: @AdamSołtan can you please include [mcve] in your question? (no, it doesn't need to produce correct result or even finish executing, but it does need to compile)

Comment: @AdamSołtan for your algorithm, you never check dupes in B and C. and you potentially (incorrectly) remove 2 times from A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

void RemoveDuplicates(std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> &vectors)
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> count;

    for (auto& vec : vectors)
    {
        for (auto str : vec)
        {
            count[str]++;
        }
    }


    for (auto& vec : vectors)
    {
        auto it = std::remove_if(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
                                 [&count](const std::string& str) { return count[str] > 1; });
        vec.erase(it, vec.end());
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> myvectors = { {"a", "b"}, { "b", "c" }, { "b", "c" } };
    RemoveDuplicates(myvectors);

    return 0;
}
```